# "FileNotFoundException" al leer/escribir archivos

Tags: c#

## Jolly Jumpers

Una secuencia es “Jolly Jumper” si el valor absoluto de las diferencias entre valores, existe en la cadena proporcionada.

```
Entrada: una cadena con números
Salida: true/ false 
Prueba: 
1432 : true
5142 : false
```

Este es el código

```
using System;
using System.IO;
using System.Text;
using System.Text.RegularExpressions;

namespace JollyJumpers
{
    class MainClass
    {
        public static void Main(string[] args)
        {
            try
            {
                StreamReader inFile = new StreamReader("input.in");
                StreamWriter outFile = new StreamWriter("output.out");
                MatchCollection matches = Regex.Matches(inFile.ReadLine(), @"\d+");
                int quantity;
                int[] numbers;
                int[] results;

                while (!inFile.EndOfStream)
                {
                    quantity = Convert.ToInt32(matches[0].ToString());
                    numbers = new int[quantity];
                    results = new int[quantity - 1];
                    bool flag = true;

                    for (int i = 0; i < quantity; i++)
                        numbers[i] = Convert.ToInt32(matches[i + 1].ToString());

                    for (int i = 0; i < quantity - 1; i++)
                        results[i] = Math.Abs(numbers[i] - numbers[i + 1]);

                    for (int i = 0; i < quantity - 2; i++)
                    {
                        if (Math.Abs(results[i] - results[i + 1]) != 1)
                        {
                            flag = false;
                            break;
                        }
                    }

                    if (flag)
                        outFile.WriteLine("Jolly");
                    else
                        outFile.WriteLine("Not Jolly");

                    matches = Regex.Matches(inFile.ReadLine(), @"\d+");

                    numbers = null;
                    results = null;
                }
                Console.Write("Finishing the Program");
                Console.Read();
                inFile.Close();
                outFile.Close();

            }
            catch (System.IO.FileNotFoundException)
            {
                Console.WriteLine("File does not exist");
                Console.Read();
            }
            catch
            {
                Console.WriteLine("Something Unexpected happened");
                Console.Read();
            }

        }
    }
}
```

Cuando se ejecuta el código aparece el siguiente mensaje en la consola

```
File does not exist
```

¿Cuál es el problema?

Comment: ¿Puedes poner el segundo problema en otra pregunta?  Además cual es el error que te sale y en que parte del código?

Comment: File does not exist" Me aparecde a la hora de correr el codig

Comment: Ese mensaje sale como resultado del `FileNotFoundException` puedes depurar el código para ver en que línea de código realmente ocurre el problema?

Comment: File does not exist a la hora de correrlo en la pantalla en consola no entiendo por que no me funciona el code

Comment: El primer error podría estar en `input.in`. Estas seguro que el archivo existe y está localizado en la misma carpeta donde se ejecuta tu programa?

Comment: en cual carpeta bin,obj,Properties?

Comment: no esta el archivo input

Comment: En la carpeta `bin\Debug` o `bin\Release`

Comment: No hay ningún archivo llamado asi

Comment: Esa línea de código que hace?

Comment: @AndresCamachoAguilar Cuando estas **intentado** abrir un archivo, se **captura** el error para que puedas manejarlo, en este caso tu codigo solo muestra el mensaje `File does not exist`

Comment: Esto es la tarea?

Comment: Andres, necesitas los archivos físicamente para que puedas aplicar el regex en input.in y escribir dentro del archivo output.out, revisa mi respuesta, te puede ayudar.

Answer (score 3):

En primer lugar deberías indicar una ruta para los archivo, al menos usar

```
string pathInput = Path.Combine(Application.StartupPath, "input.in");

StreamReader inFile = new StreamReader(pathInput);
```

Esto al menos indica de forma precisa que tomaras la ruta del lugar donde ejecuta la aplicación. Si lo necesitas podrias cambiar el [Application.StartupPath](https://msdn.microsoft.com/es-es/library/system.windows.forms.application.startuppath%28v=vs.110%29.aspx) por la ruta fija donde estan los archivos (tambien puede definirla en el archivo de configuracion `app.config`)

Por otro lado recuerda que si ejecutas desde el VS este compila el .exe en la carpeta `bin\Debug` por lo que debes asegurarte que los archivos que intentas acceder esten en esa carpeta.

Si los archivos estan integrados al proyecto en el VS, o sea si los visualizas en el Solution Explorer podrian copiarse junto al .exe en la carpeta de debug solo cambiando la opcion de las propiedades del archivo `Copy to Output directory` con la opcion `Copy always`

---

Por otro lado podria mencionar que no necesitas recorrer de esa forma el archivo, si vas a recorrer las lineas y si el archivo no es muy grande, podrias cargarlo a memoria usando

```
string pathInput = Path.Combine(Application.StartupPath, "input.in");

string[] lineas = File.ReadAllLines(pathInput);

foreach(string linea in lineas){

   MatchCollection matches = Regex.Matches(linea, @"\d+");
   //resto codigo
}
```

El `File.ReadAllLines` deja el codigo mas prolijo y legible para interacturar con las líneas del archivo.

Answer (score 0):

Al obtener el Error `FileNotFoundException` se refiere estrictamente a que no encuentra el archivo especificado. Sugiero definas las rutas donde se encontraran los archivos por ejemplo:

```
 string pathInput = @"c:\data\input.in";
 string pathOutput = @"c:\data\output.out";

 StreamReader inFile = new StreamReader(pathInput);
                StreamWriter outFile = new StreamWriter(pathOutput);
                MatchCollection matches = Regex.Matches(inFile.ReadLine(), @"\d+");
...
...
...
```

En caso de que no existan los archivos, puedes agregar una validación que permita crear los archivos e introducir dentro de ellos, los datos que desees, por ejemplo:

```
string pathInput = @"c:\data\input.in";
string pathOutput = @"c:\data\output.out";

    if (!File.Exists(pathInput))  //No existe, crea el archivo input.in.
       {
        File.Create(pathInput);
        TextWriter tw = new StreamWriter(path);
        tw.WriteLine("Información para el archivo input.in!");
        tw.Close();
       }
    if (!File.Exists(pathOutput))  //No existe, crea el archivo Output.out.
       {
        File.Create(pathOutput);
        TextWriter tw = new StreamWriter(path);
        tw.WriteLine("Información para el archivo Output.out!");
        tw.Close();
        }
```